# How do I link a View class to the XML screen?

Tags: java, android

I am still learning Java and how to use Eclipse but I have a XML main activity file (the graphical layout) and a Java file named Mainscreen that extends Activity.

Inside the Mainscreen file I have a Class named myView which extends View and I can get it to display on the device screen by calling `setContentView(new MyView(this));` from the Mainscreen onCreate method. How do I make it so I can have the MyView be a view within the XML file?

I can also change it to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);`and then it sets it to what the XML file is but how do I have it so both are displayed.

I want it to display the screen as if it was following the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);` layout but then also have the MyView displayed as well inside a seperate View on the screen. I have tried setting it as `setContentView(R.id.view1);` but if I am being completely honest I am not 100% sure what I am doing as I am still learning.

Can someone please point me in the right direction or help me out? I have been Googling trying to figure this out and I'm a little lost.

Thanks

EDIT: added code below

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainScreen" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:src="@drawable/title_plate" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The start of the MyView class

```
public class MyView extends View {
public MyView(Context context) {
super(context);
//setContentView(R.id.view1);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
```

The onCreate for the main file itself

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
setContentView(new MyView(this));
//View circleView = (View)findViewById(R.id.view1); 
//circleView = (new MyView(this));
//circleView = findViewById(R.id.view1);
}
```

I won't post all the other stuff the file contains as it would seem pretty pointless as it is just code to do what I want it to do.

Comment: Post your XML file and the code you wrote to achieve this.

Comment: Added code, the // out lines is me trying to figure it out by the way

Comment: Great. This will make it easier for us to see where you are at and provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

**Take this Class as your view class**

```
package com.example.utils.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FontButton extends Button {
    public static Typeface FONT_NAME;

    public FontButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (FONT_NAME == null)
            FONT_NAME = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/Signika-Regular.ttf");
        this.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);
    }

    public FontButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (FONT_NAME == null)
            FONT_NAME = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/Signika-Regular.ttf");
        this.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);
    }

    public FontButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if (FONT_NAME == null)
            FONT_NAME = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/Signika-Regular.ttf");
        this.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);
    }
}





**Now in the Xml file**



  <com.example.utils.views.FontButton 
        android:id="@+id/register_user_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:background="@drawable/enter_pin"
        android:onClick="@string/countryCodeClick"
        android:text="@string/default_country_code" />
```

Comment: I'm confused, this code looks to be to do with a button. My question was asking about setting up views. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I have given you an example : 

You can take it this way 

Java class extends view instead of Textview

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't help much. I am asking about how I set up a view to an XML

Answer (score 0):

The XML view is a description of a class hierarchy.  Each object in the XML represents a java class that inherits from [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).  The instances that contain other class inherit from a subclass, [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html).

When you make a call like this: `myActivity.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);`

What you are in effect doing is instantiating all of the objects defined in the view and associating them with your Activity.  You can use your custom View subclasses in the XML by supplying the full package name (e.g. `com.myapp.MyViewSubclass`) in the XML definition.  Here is a concrete example:

```
<com.myapp.MyViewSubclass
        android:id="@+id/myView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now, within the java code, if you wanted to access this view, after calling `myActivity.setContentView` you would do something like this:

```
MyViewSubclass instance = (MyViewSubclass)myActivity.findViewById(R.id.myView1);
```

So R.java is a file that is created automatically by parsing all your XML files.  R.id.myView1 is an integer that resolves to the item inside your XML file, and it will reference the object that you loaded once you load it using setContentView.

Comment: Ok I think I am starting to understand it a little better now. I tried your code for the MyViewSubclass instance = (MyViewSubclass)myActivity.findViewById(R.id.myView1); but it says "Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method"